# ASP.NET MVC trying to redirect to another page after submit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, button, model-view-controller, submit

In the View, I have the following code :-

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("addsurvey","survey")) {
```

When the submit button is pressed, the event

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult addsurvey(Survey oSurvey)
    {
```

is called but then the page errors because it can't find addsurvey.aspx etc pages.  What am i don't wrong.  The page that the form is on is called survey.  Why can't it just refresh the page or do i need to

```
response.redirect("/survey");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method must return an `ActionResult`. Usually it's a `ViewResult` when you use `return View()`, but if you want to redirect to another action, there is another return type. Just do :

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "survey");
```

(just replace Index with the target action)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the addsurvey action method you can call
View();( There must be addsurvey.cshtml in the controller folder of project's  View folder  )
View("actionName")  ;( There must be actionName.cshtml in the controller folder of project's View folder  )  or
RedirectoAction("actionName","controllerName") ( There must be actionName.cshtml in the controllerName folder of project's View folder  )